# Model method to update count of integer field

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

So I have a PickupSchedule model that has a field `current_count`. When a donation gets submitted, the current_count increases. When a donation gets rescheduled, it decreases and the new route increases. There is also an exemption process which does the same thing. In order to avoid duplicate code I was hoping to do something like below however it does not work (attribute error - `'PickupSchedule' object has no attribute 'decrease_current_count'`). I know I can += the field within the form save but I'd like to have it in one single spot rather then being it two seperate forms.

models.py

```
class PickupSchedule(models.Model):

    current_count= models.IntegerField(blank=True, default=0)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.route 

    def decrease_current_count(self):
        self.current_count -= 1
        self.save()

    def increase_current_count(self):
        self.current_count += 1
        self.save()
```

forms.py save

```
def save(self,force_insert=False, force_update=False,commit=True):

    donor = super(RescheduleForm,self).save(commit=False)

    # Update the old route current count
    old_route = self.old_route
    old_route.decrease_current_count()

    # Update the new route current count
    new_route = PickupSchedule.objects.get(pickup_id = self.new_id)
    new_route.increase_current_count()

    if commit:
        donor.save()

    return donor
```

Comment: Can you be more specific than attribute error?

Comment: def decrease_current_count():  should be def decrease_current_count(self):

Comment: Updated code above with exact error and I did have (self) within the method call, I accidentally left it out while posting.